# NPN high-edge flipflop

Tags: transistors, flipflop, npn

I'm looking for a design of an NPN flip-flop that reverses its output when the input is brought high. I'm looking to use the 2N2222 for this purpose.

Comment: "that reverses its output when the input is brought high."  That is not how a flipflop works.

Comment: [Here's a discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/351026/38098) where the issue is about bringing the input low instead of high. Perhaps this will help. (An inverter would be an obvious adaptation.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a divide-by-10 counter circuit I designed for fun on a steamy August evening about 20 years ago. Might give you some ideas. I used fourteen 2N4401s but any jellybean NPN transistors with similar hFE should work. I built it as well as simulating it, and it worked fine. It's a Johnson counter so it  uses one more FF than required to divide by 10, but the decoding to 1 of 10 is much easier than a straight binary counter.

The three diodes in series (10 triplets) represent red LEDs with a Vf of around 1.8V.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to solder this..

1 Bit binary counter with discrete components

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvjSMd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>